# Java Swing KeyStrokes: how to make CTRL-modifier work

Tags: java, swing, action, keystroke

In the following program, why does hitting the <kbd>a</kbd> key print *"hello, world"* while hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> doesn't?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyStrokeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        /* add a new action named "foo" to the panel's action map */
        panel.getActionMap().put("foo", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("hello, world");
                }
            });

        /* connect two keystrokes with the newly created "foo" action:
           - a
           - CTRL-a
        */
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap();
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(Character.valueOf('a'), 0), "foo");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(Character.valueOf('a'), InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "foo");

        /* display the panel in a frame */
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How could I fix it that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> works as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I find it easier to use:

```
KeyStroke a = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A");
KeyStroke controlA = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control A");
```

or:

```
KeyStroke controlA = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
```

Answer (score 7):

Dude, use this

```
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK), "foo");
```

Comment: Interesting I made my suggestion before this posting, plus I gave you other alternatives that you might be able to use in different situations. I guess I won't go to all the trouble the next time.

Comment: @Thomas: I dont know whether I am correct, but the reason that your code might have not worked because in the first case, you were referring to a simple character 'a'. Where-in in the second case you are referring a combination of keys which is an ASCII and a scan value(Ctrl key). I feel it should have been associated with events properly.

Comment: @camickr - I'm sorry, that was an honest mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the above code will work.

Big picture - <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> are read as different keystrokes the same as <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> would be different.

Comment: The OP knows "Ctrl-A" and "A" are different keystrokes.